# VB.NET Callback on collected delegate detected on invoke

Tags: vb.net, keyboard, hook

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Reflection.Emit
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Windows
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices
Public Class MicroScope_login
    Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Integer) As Short
    Public Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Int32
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = &H20
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = &H40
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10
    Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = &H1
    Private Const WH_KEYBOARD_LL As Integer = 13
    Private Const WM_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H100
    Private Const WM_SYSKEYDOWN As Integer = &H104
    Private Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312
    Private Const VK_LWIN As Integer = &H5B
    Private Const VK_RWIN As Integer = &H5C
    Private Delegate Function LowLevelKeyboardProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As IntPtr
    Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As StringBuilder, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
    Private Shared hookID As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    
    'keyboard function button Block
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function RegisterHotKey(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifiers As Integer, ByVal vk As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function UnregisterHotKey(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal lpfn As LowLevelKeyboardProc, ByVal hMod As IntPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As UInteger) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(ByVal hhk As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function CallNextHookEx(ByVal hhk As IntPtr, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function GetModuleHandle(ByVal lpModuleName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
    Public Function HookCallback(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr 'call keyboard hook
        If nCode = 0 AndAlso (wParam = New IntPtr(WM_KEYDOWN) OrElse wParam = New IntPtr(WM_SYSKEYDOWN)) Then
            Dim vkCode As Integer = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam)
            If vkCode = VK_LWIN OrElse vkCode = VK_RWIN Then
                Return New IntPtr(1)
            ElseIf vkCode = Keys.ControlKey OrElse vkCode = Keys.Escape OrElse (Control.ModifierKeys And Keys.Alt) = Keys.Alt AndAlso vkCode = Keys.Tab OrElse (Control.ModifierKeys And Keys.LWin) = Keys.LWin AndAlso vkCode = Keys.D Then
                Return New IntPtr(1)
            End If
        End If
        Return CallNextHookEx(hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam)

    End Function

    Private Sub MicroScope_login_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 'Form_load
        
        Use_reason.Items.Clear()
        Use_reason.Items.Add("FA Use")
        Use_reason.Items.Add("Bonding use")
        Use_reason.Items.Add("Lam Use")
        Use_reason.Items.Add("other")
        Use_reason.Items.Add("Sorting")
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        txtUserID.ShortcutsEnabled = False
        hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, AddressOf HookCallback, GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName), 0)' Ctrl + ESC Block 
        GetCursorPos(Pos)

        Me.KeyPreview = True ' Set the KeyPreview property of the form to True
        AddHandler Me.KeyDown, AddressOf MicroScope_login_KeyDown ' Add the KeyDown event handler to the form

        If Not DBInitial() Then

            MsgBox("Unconnected database,program close")

            Me.Close()

            Exit Sub

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Login_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Login.Click 'Login button

        If txtUserID.Text = "" Or Use_reason.SelectedItem = "" Or txtUserID.Text.Length <> 8 Or txtUserID.Text.StartsWith("3") Or txtUserID.Text.StartsWith("4") Or txtUserID.Text.StartsWith("5") Or txtUserID.Text.StartsWith("6") Or txtUserID.Text.StartsWith("7") Or txtUserID.Text.StartsWith("8") Or txtUserID.Text.StartsWith("9") Then
            MsgBox("WordID & Use_reason can't null" & vbCrLf & "WordID not Correct")

        ElseIf WriteLineStatus("INSERT INTO FA_MicroScope_list(UserID,Use_reason,dTime,LogOffTime)values('" & txtUserID.Text & "','" & Use_reason.SelectedItem & "','" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "',0)") Then
            MsgBox("Login Success")
            Me.Hide()
        End If

        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer2.Enabled = True
        ThreadingTimer.Enabled = True
        GetCursorPos(Pos_new)

        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookID)
        UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1)

    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Timer1.Stop()

        GetCursorPos(Pos_new)
        If Pos.X = Pos_new.X And Pos.Y = Pos_new.Y And key_input = False Then
            Me.Show()
            txtUserID.Clear()
            Use_reason.SelectedIndex = -1
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            Timer2.Enabled = False
        Else
            Pos.X = Pos_new.X
            Pos.Y = Pos_new.Y
            Timer1.Start()

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Timer2.Stop()

        If IsFormActive() = True Then
            key_input = True
        Else
            key_input = False
        End If

        Timer2.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MicroScope_login_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
        'Block Alt+F4
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Or e.KeyCode = Keys.F4 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub MicroScope_login_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) 
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookID)
        UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        ' Block Win+D
        ' Handle hotkey messages
        If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
            ' Check if hotkey ID=1 and Win+D combination was pressed
            If m.WParam.ToInt32() = 1 Then
                m.Result = New IntPtr(1)
                Return
            End If
        End If

        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
    Private Function IsFormActive() As Boolean
        'Detect the keyboard is triggered in the from
        ' Get the handle of the active window
        Dim hwnd As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow()

        ' Get the title of the active window
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(256)
        GetWindowText(hwnd, sb, sb.Capacity)

        ' Compare the title of the active window with the title of the form
        Return sb.ToString().Equals(Me.Text)
    End Function

    Private Sub txtUserID_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        'WordID only can input number
        If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = Chr(8) Then
            e.Handled = False
        Else
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThreadingTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ThreadingTimer.Tick

        ThreadingTimer.Stop()

        Try

            If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F2) Then

                Me.Visible = True
                If WriteLineStatus("UPDATE FA_MicroScope_List SET LogOffTime= '" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "' Where UserID ='" & txtUserID.Text & "'") Then
                    MsgBox("Login Off Success!!")
                End If
                txtUserID.Clear()
                Use_reason.SelectedIndex = -1
                hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, AddressOf HookCallback, GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName), 0) 'Ctrl+ESC Block ?e|!
                GetCursorPos(Pos)

                Me.KeyPreview = True ' Set the KeyPreview property of the form to True
                AddHandler Me.KeyDown, AddressOf MicroScope_login_KeyDown ' Add the KeyDown event handler to the form
            End If
            If Me.Visible = False Then
                ThreadingTimer.Start()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub


End Class
```

HI !! This is my first time writing vb.net,and i design the micro scope Login System.
In the code,  I block Win+ESC、Win+D key、Tab+Alt...etc combination Key
After successful login, press the F2 key can logout,and go right back into the form.

but when I press F2 and return to the form, after 10 minutes of inactivity, it will appear
collected delegate of type MicroScope +LowLevelKeyboardProc::Invoke' error

i try to create variable for LowLevelKeyboardProc,but still error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```vb
hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, AddressOf HookCallback, GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName), 0)
```

you are creating a delegate for the `HookCallback` method but you don't keep a reference to it. When there are no managed references to an object, it becomes eligible for garbage collection and may be cleaned up by the GC at any time. The fact that your error message is talking about a collected delegate of the relevant type, that is almost certainly what's happening. You should assign that delegate to a variable that will remain in scope as long as you want to be able to invoke that delegate, which probably means a field of that same class. You can then pass that field as an argument in the function call above:

```vb
someField = AddressOf HookCallback
hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, someField, GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName), 0)
```

Comment: I think I probably know how to fix it , Thanks!!